# SQL profiler not showing RPC calls

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I am running SQL profiler to trace the sql queries being executed, the trace is showing only Audit logs, not the sql commands being executed.
Can somebody tell me how to get the sql commands also?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the "Events Selection" tab of the trace definition, make sure that the `TextData` column is checked for `RPC:Completed` events.

(This is unchecked in the default trace definition)